# Organizing rows following cartesian product of 3 columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, permutation, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have 3 lists like in the following reproducible example:

```
year = [2015, 2016, 2017] 
month = [1, 2] 
ids = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
```

What I would like to create is a very simple task of creating a final dataframe where I had the 3 columns sorting its rows as a permutation or cartesian product of the column values.

Something like:

[image]

At the end I would like to add an 'Epoque' column where the reference is: December of 2014 is equal to '1', January of 2015 is equal to '2', February of 2015 is equal to '3', and so on (The sequence will continue with initial reference Dec-2014 = '1' (for the 'Epoque' value))...

The final desired output would have this look:

[image]

**EDIT**:

Question edited thanks to the great feedback of @jezrael. He provided me the line missing to achieve the desired df but only missing the 'Epoque' column.

My code suggested would be the following (lacking the 'Epoque' desired column):

```
import itertools
s = [ [ 2015, 2016, 2017], [1, 2], ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'] ]
z = list(itertools.product(*s))
df = pd.DataFrame(z) # Trivial line provided kindly by @jezrael I didn't know.
```

Any help regarding how to achieve the 'Epoque' column efficiently, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create your dataframe from those 3 list, or from the list of tuples you speak of at the end of your post?

Comment: The image of the final desired output doesn't match the sort you will get from `list(itertools.product(*s))`.

Comment: Check edited answer, is possible define last maximal value of month-year?

Comment: @StatisticDean I would say the first lists I defined at the beginning of my post. I noticed I had a mistake before: I defined the list of characters x, y, z, w as objects (without the quote mark inside the list). I have now changed that so that it is a list of character values: ids = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'].

Comment: @user3471881 wasn't aware of this. Thanks for input. Will check thoroughly my table I posted as png file. I can have mistakes because I did it fast following a personal logic to do the permutation, but I would trust more the results of itertools than my manual counting. Will check it, thanks!

Comment: @jezrael thought in that alternative as well. Used in my Jupyter Notebook the following useful line of code: df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format="%Y-%m-%d") + MonthEnd(1). Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas `datetime`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(z, columns=['year', 'month', 'id'])

base = pd.Timestamp('2014-12-01')
dates = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month']].assign(day=1))

df['epoch'] = dates.dt.to_period('M') - base.to_period('M') + 1

# alternative
df['epoch'] = (dates.dt.year - base.year)*12 + (dates.dt.month - base.month) + 1

print(df)

    year  month id  epoch
0   2015      1  x      2
1   2015      1  y      2
2   2015      1  z      2
3   2015      1  w      2
4   2015      2  x      3
5   2015      2  y      3
...
18  2017      1  z     26
19  2017      1  w     26
20  2017      2  x     27
21  2017      2  y     27
22  2017      2  z     27
23  2017      2  w     27
```

Comment: After trying several examples with different timestamps for a variety of months and years I have found your answer the most simple and easy-to-apply. Thus, I tag your answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary created by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) defined with start and end `date`s:

```
import itertools
s = [ [ 2015, 2016, 2017], [1, 2], ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'] ]
z = list(itertools.product(*s))

a = 'Dec-2014'
b = 'Dec-2018'
r = pd.date_range(a, b, freq='MS')
d = dict(zip(r, range(1, len(r) + 1)))

df = pd.DataFrame(z, columns=['year','month','id'])
df['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month']].assign(day=1)).map(d)
```

---

```
print (df)
    year  month id  epoch
0   2015      1  x      2
1   2015      1  y      2
2   2015      1  z      2
3   2015      1  w      2
4   2015      2  x      3
5   2015      2  y      3
6   2015      2  z      3
7   2015      2  w      3
8   2016      1  x     14
9   2016      1  y     14
10  2016      1  z     14
11  2016      1  w     14
12  2016      2  x     15
13  2016      2  y     15
14  2016      2  z     15
15  2016      2  w     15
16  2017      1  x     26
17  2017      1  y     26
18  2017      1  z     26
19  2017      1  w     26
20  2017      2  x     27
21  2017      2  y     27
22  2017      2  z     27
23  2017      2  w     27
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to go through all variables with multiple for loop.

```
#Set the start date of your epoch (Here november 2014 is epoch 0)
month_0 = 11
year_0 = 2014
year_col = []
month_col = []
id_col = []
epoch_col = []
for j1 in ids:
    for j2 in month:
        for j3 in year:
            year_col.append(j3)
            month_col.append(j2)
            id_col.append(j1)
            epoch = (j3-year_0)*12 +(j2-month_0)
            epoch_col.append(epoch)
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':year_col,'month':month_col,'id':id_col,'epoch':epoch_col})
```